# Subdominio wildcard configurar redirección

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

Hola estoy trabajando con cpanel he configurado mi subdominios *.dominio.com para crear distintos perfiles url ejemplo "marcos.dominio.com, mario.dominio.com" cree la ruta del subdominio dentro de mi carpeta public_html quedando "/public_html/*wildcard*.dominio.com" dentro de esa carpeta genere un .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.dominio\.com
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?id=%1 [L]
```

según tengo entendido este código hace que cuando entre a la url "marcos.dominio.com" en el index.php se vera el id "marcos" este index.php se encuentra en la carpeta "/public_html/*wildcard*.dominio.com" me gustaria que el RewriteRule redireccione a la carpeta principal "/public_html/index.php" en donde tengo todos los archivos del sistema sin cambiar la url manteniendo todos los parámetros que le envié en la ruta

en mi carpeta "/public_html" tambien tengo un htaccess para crear la url amigable

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

De verdad no entiendo mucho sobre htaccess alguna guía sobre esto gracias ?

Comment: Con cpanel no necesitas configurar rewrite para ese tipo de operaciones, según entendi tienes un subdominio llamado wildcard.dominio.com el cual apunta a public_html/wildcard.dominio.com y deseas que ese subdominio apunte directamente a public_html, cierto?

Comment: Si @ernestojimenez que apunte a public_html sin ser cambiada la url

Comment: Ah sin ser cambiada la url, ya eso es otra cosa, dependera de lo que tengas puesto en public_html